# Passing an IBOutlet variable to another class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, variables, iboutlet

I'm trying to take an IBOutlet of type UITextField, and use that variable in a function with let constants from another class... How would I go about dong this?

**Example:**

- Class A

  ```
  Import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet weak var userInputTextField: UITextField!
      @IBOutlet weak var labelToBeUpdated: UILabel!
  }
  ```
- Class B

  ```
  Import Foundation

  class Data {
      let x = 10
      let y = 100
  }
  ```

I would like to take the userInputTextField in Class A and multiply it by x in Class B, then divide it by y in Class B... (userInput * x) / y

Thanks

Comment: how u would multply an outlet with x ? Could you please explain in detail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't multiply `IBOutlet`s  like text fields ;-)

- Create an instance of class `Data`
- Check if the text value of the text field is convertible to `Int` and do the math by accessing `Data`'s properties.

---

```
let data = Data()

if let userInput = Int(userInputTextField.text) {
  let result = (userInput * data.x) / data.y
}
```